# Android Receive Silent Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

hello i have android application and i used Firebase notification and its working good ,, now i need to receive silent push without alert or anything ,,, i tried some idea and its working when app is running but when app in background or terminated its not working ! if anyone have idea to sole this issue please tell me :) this is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Boolean isSilent;
    String Silent = "";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
                bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                Log.d(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
//            remoteMessage.getData().get("screen_id")
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                sendNotificationData(bundle.getString("data_title"), bundle.getString("data_body"), bundle.getString("screen_id"));

            } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification(), bundle.getString("screen_id"));
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notificationR, String screenId) {
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intentNotification = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intentNotification.putExtra("screen_id", screenId);
        Log.v("sendNotification ", " >>>>>####>>>>>>>>  " + screenId);
        // finish previous activity
        if (!Silent.equals("yes")) {
            intentNotification.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 50, intentNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle(notificationR.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notificationR.getBody())
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setLargeIcon(icon(getApplicationContext()))
                    .setLights(Color.LTGRAY, 1000, 1000)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(notificationR.getTitle())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));


            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            //  '|' Binary OR Operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand. to ensure no conflict on the flags
            notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

            nManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notification);

        }
    }


    private void sendNotificationData(String dataTitle, String dataBody, String screenId) {
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intentNotification = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intentNotification.putExtra("screen_id", screenId);


        if (!Silent.equals("yes")) {
            intentNotification.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 50, intentNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle(dataTitle)
                    .setContentText(dataBody)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setLargeIcon(icon(getApplicationContext()))
                    .setLights(Color.LTGRAY, 1000, 1000)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(dataTitle)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            //  '|' Binary OR Operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand. to ensure no conflict on the flags
            notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

            nManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notification);
        }
       @Override
        public boolean zzE(Intent intent) {
            isSilent = intent.hasExtra("silent");
            if (isSilent) {
                Silent = "yes";
            }
            return super.zzE(intent);
        }
```

when app is running this code is working but at background or terminated its not working !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app is in Background firbase notification message received on 'System tray' that's why FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived not called.

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.

Try to sent data payload that will call onMessageReceived. and your code will 
 work
For data message....
Get firebase token from FirebaseInstanceIdService and sent it to app server.
Google have very good documentation to sent it [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)

You can sent it using php also.

Then on onMessageReceived

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String screen = remoteMessage.getData().get("screen");

        sendNotification(title, body, screen );}
```

For Server side php implementation

```
    <?php  
$path_to_fcm = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$headers = array(
    'Authorization:key='YOUR_SERVER_KEY,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
);

$reg_id_array = array
(
    'token1',
    'token2'
)

$mesg = array
(   
    'title'=>$_POST['title'], 
    'body'=> $_POST['message'], 
    'url'=>$_POST['Screen'],

);

$fields = array("registration_ids"=>$reg_id_array, 'data'=>$mesg);


$payload = json_encode($fields);
$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$Qresult = curl_exec($curl_session);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl_session , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl_session);
if ($httpcode==200) {
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

Sorry bad English

Comment: thanks for replay ,, but can you explain how to "sent data payload that will call onMessageReceived"????

Comment: This link can help you
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Answer (score 0):

A Notification contains 2 thigs:

- the `notification` itself and
- extra `data`.

You seem to have `data` in your code because of values such as `screen_id`, ``` data_title``etc. It actually looks you are reading everything from the ```data` part, I will leave the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) here just in case. In the first table in that page explains where each notification is handled.

Since you use `data`, all notifications will be manged in `onMessageReceived`, so the only think I can think of is you terminated the app from Android Studio (through the *Stop* button).

Doing so, the App terminates, and also does background Firebase instance. All processes exit. So try closing it from the mobile, and report if it worked.

Good luck.